# intellij - spring-boot is not being recognised (unmapped Spring-boot annotated configuration classes)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3, spring-boot

I am using intellij and all plugins for spring are activated , How to add spring-boot annotated configuration classes to intellij IDE .
I am getting following Warning :

Spring Configuration Check
   Unmapped Spring configuration files found. Please configure/setup Spring facet for modules:               exampleApp (13 files)

Answer (score 28):

It's not specific to spring-boot, it's merely IntelliJ telling you that your Spring configuration classes or XML resources are not being referenced by your project settings.  Simply add the Spring facet to your module, then click the add button in the right panel.  IntelliJ should find your configuration classes or XML resources and you simply need to select them.

All this does is allow IntelliJ to perform inspections on Spring beans you reference in your classes.

[image]

Comment: Why does intellij not simply do this automatically?

Comment: Are there any way to add all configuration classes from dependency jar (ex. spring-boot-actuator1.2.5.RELEASE.jar have InfoEndpoint, HealthEndpoint, ...) ?